# How to change order inside foreach using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-script

I have a created a for each loop to load all the script files from my build folder dynamically in the footer with for development and production mode. This way I don't need to manually replace the script files.

But I have a problem, I don't know how to change the order of the files to a specific order.

It should be: Runtime, Vendors, Main.

This is my PHP code:

```
// First check if "JS" folder exist to prevent errors.
if(is_dir(THEME_DIR_ASSETS . '/js')) {
    // Enqueue all scripts.
    function nm_enqueue_scripts() {
    $directoryJS = new DirectoryIterator(THEME_DIR_ASSETS . '/js');

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array(), null, false);

        foreach ($directoryJS as $file) {
            if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'js') {
            $fullName = basename($file);
            $name = substr(basename($fullName), 0, strpos(basename($fullName), '.'));

            wp_enqueue_script($name, THEME_DIR_JS . '/' . $fullName, $name, null, true);
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nm_enqueue_scripts');
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think your approach is flawed. WordPress allows for dependencies to be set on scripts & styles - so I would always define the runtime & vendors as dependency of my main style/script and only enqueue the latter. As for changing environments, why/how is that currently a problem?

Comment: You shouldn't be dequeing the jQuery that comes with WordPress, in order to do what you want you'll need to declare dependencies. I would avoid scanning the folder and enquing like that

Comment: Why not Tom? I am only using custom JS no jQuery and if I use plugins it is a minimal amount of recently updated plugins which supports newer jQuery version.